# R Unmarked error: obsCovData does not have M*obsNum rows

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I am fairly new to R and trying to model occupancy probability for my species (Lepilemur). I have 21 sites, 2 site covariates and 3 observation covariates. My code is as follows:

```
lepi<-read.csv("Lepilemur2.csv", header=T)
nSites<- 21

lepiDetects<- lepi[,2:4]
lepiSiteCovars<-as.data.frame(lepi[,5:6])
lepiObsCovars<-as.data.frame(lepi[,7:9])
detect<-apply(lepiDetects, 2, function(x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
umf<-unmarkedFrameOccu(y=detect, siteCovs= lepiSiteCovars, obsCovs=lepiObsCovars)
```

However when I run the final line of code i receive the following error:
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “unmarkedFrame” object: obsCovData does not have M*obsNum rows

In my global environment it says I have 21 observations of 3 variables.

Any help you can offer me would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Buffy

Comment: Hi! Since you data frame is small, do you mind doing dput(lepi) and pasting the output as part of your question? This way we can see what is the data you are working with, and where the error comes from :)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I would do

```
umf<-unmarkedFrameOccu(y=detect, siteCovs= lepiSiteCovars, 
obsCovs=list(lepiObsCovars=lepiObsCovars))
```

Details about why that will work are as follows. The manual for unmarkedFrameOccu states you can use a data frame but there's something weird about it:

> obsCovs: Either a named list of ‘data.frame’s of covariates that vary
>             within sites, or a ‘data.frame’ with RxJ rows in site-major
>             order.

I tested it using the example from the library `unmarked`, we simulate some data:

```
library(unmarked)

R <- 4 # number of sites
J <- 3 # number of visits
y <- matrix(c(
   1,1,0,
   0,0,0,
   1,1,1,
   1,0,1), nrow=R, ncol=J, byrow=TRUE)

site.covs <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=factor(c('A','B','A','B')))

obs.covs <- list(
   x3 = matrix(c(
      -1,0,1,
      -2,0,0,
      -3,1,0,
      0,0,0), nrow=R, ncol=J, byrow=TRUE),
   x4 = matrix(c(
      'a','b','c',
      'd','b','a',
      'a','a','c',
      'a','b','a'), nrow=R, ncol=J, byrow=TRUE))
```

The example from the vignette works, using a list:

```
umf <- unmarkedFrameOccu(y=y, siteCovs=site.covs, 
    obsCovs=obs.covs)
```

But if we do something similar to your example, we get the error:

```
x4_df <- data.frame(obs.covs$x4)
umf <- unmarkedFrameOccu(y=y, siteCovs=site.covs, 
        obsCovs=x4_df)

Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “unmarkedFrame” object: obsCovData does not have M*obsNum rows.
```

So we have to do:

```
x4_list <- list(x4=data.frame(obs.covs$x4))
umf <- unmarkedFrameOccu(y=y, siteCovs=site.covs, 
            obsCovs=x4_list)
```